# Calling Macro in extended assembly

Tags: c, assembly, riscv, riscv32

I want to add a macro in in extended assembly in c code. is this possible ?

I am looking for something like this:

```
   ANY_MACRO (Instruction) asm volatile(
        "li t0, 0xcafebabe;"
        "li t1, 0x00c0fee;"
        <----///Replace instruction here like ()////---->
        :[dummy_output]"=r"(dummy_output_var)
        :[dummy_var_addr]"r"(&dummy_var1)
        :"t0","t1","t2","a0"
        );
```

Note: I am also manipulating some C-Variables in this Macro as shown above!

Compiler: GCC
Assembly: RISCV

Comment: Have you tried it? Is it working? Then yes you can do it. Is it not working, then describe the error and post any error message.

Comment: You could ask the compiler to give you the preprocessed output, to see the result of the macro invocation.

Comment: Inline assembler isn't standardized, so in order to get any answers, you first need to state the compiler and compiler port used.

Comment: Yes I have tried it! But it always gives some compilation error!
The compiler I am using is `GCC` and the assembly language is RISCV.

Comment: What I want to do is following:
1- Use a extended assembly in C file to simulate a specific test case on RISCV CPU
2- I want to add that extened assembly in the C-file!
3- and then I want use that same extened assembly to simulate the same test case but with different instructions!

So, WHat I am looking for is a way to write that extended assembly in C-File and them somehow use a macro which calls that extened assembly macro with an argument and I can pass an instruction to that macro as an argument to do what I have described above!

Comment: I have tried every way I know and always get some syntax error! So, Is it possible to call a macro which has extended assembly in it and we are passing an instruction as an argument to that macro to execute!

Answer (score 2):

The `__asm__` construct takes the assembly as a quoted string (a string literal), so the macro needs to produce its result as a quoted string. This can be in the form of consecutive quoted strings, which the compiler will automatically concatenate into one string, and you can use the `#` preprocessor operator to convert macro arguments into quoted strings:

```
#define INSERT_INST( inst, rd, rs2, rs1 ) #inst " " #rd "," #rs2 "," #rs1 ";"
```

If any of the arguments to your `INSERT_INST` macro are themselves macros that you want expanded, you will need another macro to replace and quote them:

```
#define Quote(x)    #x
#define INSERT_INST( inst, rd, rs2, rs1 ) Quote(inst) " " Quote(rd) "," Quote(rs2) "," Quote(rs1) ";"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working! I have tried this in my case! I just need to a reference/example as you gave above how can I call an asm block(which has the same macro inside it you gave an example above) with a with another macro which takes this macro as an input!
What I want to do is call that macro multiple times to test for different instruction!